# Showcase of modern, beautiful and appealing styles for short documents

Tags: typography, book-design, examples

I'm helping someone to typeset in LaTeX a short non-technical document (at most 20 pages). This document should be nice to read, aesthetic, with nice pictures...

LaTeX is mostly used for technical document, in which the style is very classic. But I'm sure there are ways to design more fancy layouts, including commercial brochure-like styles. Here is one example of [a nice document](https://issuu.com/inseec/docs/plaquette-inseec-msc-mba/160) (the link shows the full document):

[image]

[image]

Even if it's not the primary goal of this question, I'm also curious to see even more fancy styles, like the ones we can see in marketing brochures (I'm not in marketing, but I've to admit that they usually produce nice looking documents)... Long story short: have fun!

[image]

The goal of this question is to provide a list of such styles, together with the LaTeX code. Since it's usually important to have a style coherent between the different elements, here is a list of elements that would be great to be styled (of course I don't expect all answers to be that precise):

- title page
- section and/or chapter style
- enumerate/itemize environments
- tabulars
- figures
- table of contents
- page numbering
- footnotes
- anything you like, like special areas to emphasize a paragraph, icons...

**Have fun ;-)**

Style-related questions/answers/packages (I don't consider them as duplicates since these questions are typically less precise, or focused on a different kind of document to typeset... but some answers are really interesting and are worth being mentionned):

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60259/116348
- A nice document: https://www.principiae.be/book/pdfs/TM&Th-samplepages.pdf
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279318/116348 and the amazing project yLatex that provides many styles, packages ready to use: https://github.com/HarveySheppard/yLaTeX
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405973/116348
- [Trying to do graphical decorations in "ClassicThesis style"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86294/trying-to-do-graphical-decorations-in-classicthesis-style/86310)
- [Showcase of beautiful title page done in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85904/showcase-of-beautiful-title-page-done-in-tex)
- [shrink the line spacing with a `marginnote` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/613958/shrink-the-line-spacing-with-a-marginnote-environment)
- https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex
- http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/ctustyle/ctustyle2-doc.pdf
- [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends)
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405973/116348

Comment: Style should suit the content. “Non-technical document” leaves countless possible kinds of content, so I don't know how the question can be answered.

Comment: @Thérèse In my precise usecase, it's about presenting music projects… but I guess many people could be interested by this kind of templates with different applications in mind. The goal of this question is also to provide to the community a list of modern styles ready to use in there projects. Each user will then be able to use the style that matches his project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks. I already know this answer (see the last part of my question), but it contains very few "modern" documents. I think I saw one or two nice modern documents, but aside from yLatex, none of them are close to the kind of document we find nowadays in advertisements.

Comment: Ah, ok. But since there is now an answer for about a month now I think that it is reasonable to close the question. At least for me, the "duplicate" is close enough (feel free to disagree of course). IMHO: LaTeX is not very suitable for the kind of document that you ask for, i. e. one needs to be very skilled and/or needs a lot of time in order to be able to produce something "nice".

Comment: Even the famous E. Tufte (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte) uses (apparently) commercial software ( 
QuarkXpress and Adobe InDesign): https://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0000HL

Comment: Please, don't close the question, I don't see any advantage of closing the question as it is not off topic. Myself I may even like to write an answer in a few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, it is possible to make the "template" you sent, as an excellent `tikz` exercise. However, the code is absolulatly messy (provided on ask).

[image]